# Node.js: Is the responses going to the right user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Let's say I have this simple code that responds with a .XML file.

```
app.post '/incoming', (req,res) ->
    console.log "Hello, incoming call!"
    message = req.body.Body
    from = req.body.From

    sys.log "From: " + from + ", Message: " + message 

    test = "hello"
    r = new Twiml.Response()
    r.append(new Twiml.Say('Hello, there!' + test + ' Enter your ATM card PIN'))
    console.log(r.toString())

    res.send r.toString()
```

Is it possible that if 2 requests come at the same time, one gets the wrong response? I'm asking this because I don't fully understand how async works and if this is doing what I want it to do.

Thanks

Comment: @Raynos, I haven't actually. I've touched here and there but nothing very complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know which client the response goes to, remove all code from the body apart from code that interacts with `res` like so :

```
app.post '/incoming', (req,res) ->
    res.send r.toString()
```

Now you can see that your sending `r.toString()` to the correct response.

> Is it possible that if 2 requests come at the same time,

Even if 2 requests come at the same time, javascript is single threaded and blocking so there are never any race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is really a question about CoffeeScript scope. When you have a function, e.g.

```
(req, res) ->
```

then within that function, you can be assured that `req` and `res` will always point to the objects that were passed in to the function. The only exception is if you have a nested function with the same argument names. For instance,

```
(req, res) ->
  setTimeout ((req, res) -> console.log req, res), 1
```

will display `undefined`, `undefined` when the outer function is called with any values, because the function passed to `setTimeout` has its own `req` and `res` arguments that *shadow* the outer `req` and `res`.

Obviously you're not doing that (and well you shouldn't), so you needn't worry. Your server can be pinged tens of thousands of times per second, and each `req` and `res` will remain distinct.